# Websphere 8.5.5 Java 1.6 ошибка com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, websphere

Использую Websphere 8.5.5. Другое ничего не могу использовать, т.к. на работе только этот сервер. Обновить его тоже нет возможности.
Приложение на Java 1.6, Spring MVC, Spring Security, Hibernate, MS SQL 2008 R2.
Столкнулся с такой ошибкой при попытке развернуть простейшее приложение (взято из урока, точно ссылку не дам, не помню).
Есть вот такой pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.art.apps</groupId>
<artifactId>massproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>

    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.40</mysql.connector.version>

    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- database pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring + aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQLServer JDBC driver (JTDS) -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- logging, slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Вот такой spring-database.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!-- data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://0067-SQL02:1433/ESU;instance=MSSQLSERVER" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>orm/Users.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>orm/UserRoles.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.art.users.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDetailsService"
      class="com.art.users.service.MyUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
</bean>

<!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
                  expression="execution(* com.art.users.service.*Service.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
</aop:config>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.art.*" />

<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

При попытке войти никаких ошибок не выдаёт, но перекидывает на страницу /login?error. Прочитал тонну интернет контента, но увы, ничего сделать с этим не смог.
Весь лог сервера не могу добавить, превышает лимит символов:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:664) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.acceptsURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:275) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:495) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
... 60 common frames omitted
```

если нужен весь лог, то поделился файлом через [google диск](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4UZxY6tqcy7VnBZZTFmUjRqSG8).

Comment: у вас в pom есть упоминание mysql. возможно когда вы переделывали пример вы забыли заменить mysql на mssql. попробуйте сделать поиск по всему проекту.

Comment: Упоминание было только в pom. Удалил все упоминания о нём, пересобрал проект, но увы, ошибка та же.

Comment: посмотрите в конфигурации WSS возможно, что там есть упоминание о mysql.

Comment: WSS - WAS? Что конкретно искать? Хотя бы направление знать, куда копать. Я тоже предположил, что он (WAS), что-то запускает без моего ведома, но понять что никак не могу.

Comment: WSS - WebSphere Server. Ищите конфигурацию DataSource.

Comment: Помню там был источник данных derby, точно смогу теперь только в понедельник узнать. Его лучше удалить или как? Я использую spring data source, так почему же WSS использует какие-то свои источники?

Comment: К сожалению ответ не найден. Удалил все упоминания MySQL, удалил datasource с websphere, но ошибка остаётся. Буду признателен за идеи.